# Difference between BeforeClass and BeforeTest in TestNG

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

As we know from official TestNG documentation:

`@BeforeClass:` The annotated method will be run before the first test method in the current class is invoked.

`@BeforeTest:` The annotated method will be run before any test method belonging to the classes inside the `<test>` tag is run.

Both the above TestNG annotations look similar in functionality.  Can anyone explain the unique difference?

Comment: Once per class vs once per testcase, you can have several testcases in one class i think?

Comment: Both the annotations used to initiate before executing all the testcases. This is the similarity. Anything unique apart from this?

Comment: you have 1 Testclass, with 3 Testmethods:`@BeforeClass` will be executed once, `@BeforeTest` will be executed 3 times. thats the difference. `@BeforeClass` can be used to set up the test environment, `@BeforeTest` can be used to clean data or setup data etc...

Comment: @Dude if so, what '@BeforeMethod' does? actually both the '@BeforeClass' and '@BeforeTest' will be executed once :) '@BeforeMethod' will be executed 3 times. Yes, data clean is the main thing.

Comment: okay i was wrong, but the answer made it very clear, perfect

Answer (score 163, accepted):

SeleniumAbstractTest.class

```
public abstract class SeleniumAbstractTest {

  @BeforeSuite
  public void beforeSuite() {
    System.out.println("BeforeSuite");
  }

  @BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest() {
    System.out.println("BeforeTest");
  }

  @BeforeClass
  public void beforeClass() {
    System.out.println("BeforeClass");
  }

  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod() {
    System.out.println("BeforeMethod");
  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void afterMethod() {
    System.out.println("AfterMethod");
  }

  @AfterClass
  public void afterClass() {
    System.out.println("AfterClass");
  }

  @AfterTest
  public void afterTest() {
    System.out.println("AfterTest");
  }

  @AfterSuite
  public void afterSuite() {
    System.out.println("AfterSuite");
  }

}
```

MyTestClass1.class

```
public class MyTestClass1 extends SeleniumAbstractTest {
  
  @Test
  public void myTestMethod1() {
    System.out.println("myTestMethod1");
  }

  @Test
  public void myTestMethod2() {
    System.out.println("myTestMethod2");
  }
}
```

MyTestClass2.class

```
public class MyTestClass2 extends SeleniumAbstractTest {
  
  @Test
  public void myTestMethod3() {
    System.out.println("myTestMethod3");
  }

  @Test
  public void myTestMethod4() {
    System.out.println("myTestMethod4");
  }
}
```

If you have the following Test Suite...

```
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test1" >
    <classes>
       <class name="MyTestClass2" />
    </classes>
  </test>
 
  <test name="Test2">
    <classes>
      <class name="MyTestClass1"/>
      <class name="MyTestClass2"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

... then the output [indented for easy reading] will be

```
BeforeSuite
'   BeforeTest
'   '   BeforeClass
'   '   '   BeforeMethod
'   '   '   '   myTestMethod3
'   '   '   AfterMethod
'   '   '   BeforeMethod
'   '   '   '   myTestMethod4
'   '   '   AfterMethod
'   '   AfterClass
'   AfterTest
'   BeforeTest
'   '   BeforeClass
'   '   '   BeforeMethod
'   '   '   '   myTestMethod1
'   '   '   AfterMethod
'   '   '   BeforeMethod
'   '   '   '   myTestMethod2
'   '   '   AfterMethod
'   '   AfterClass
'   '   BeforeClass
'   '   '   BeforeMethod
'   '   '   '   myTestMethod3
'   '   '   AfterMethod
'   '   '   BeforeMethod
'   '   '   '   myTestMethod4
'   '   '   AfterMethod
'   '   AfterClass
'   AfterTest
AfterSuite
```

Comment: The bottom of this answer is exactly what I was looking for, awesome!

Comment: what about beforeGroups and AfterGroups??

Answer (score 11):

@BeforeMethod - executes before every test method e.g. The Method which uses @Test annotation

@BeforeTest - executes only before  tag given in testng.xml file.

In a nutshell, @BeforeMethod works on test defined in Java classes.
And @BeforeTest works on test defined in testng.xml i.e XML files.

Answer (score 11):

Before explaining the difference, first this is some testing terminologies

`Test suite` – Consists of one or more test tags.

`Test tag` -   Consists of one or more test classes.

`Test class` – Consists of one or more methods.

for examble

```
<suite name="suit1">
  <test name="TestTag1">
    <classes>
      <class name="TestClass1"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="TestTag2">
    <classes>
      <class name="TestClass2"/>
      <class name="TestClass3"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

`@BeforeTest` : It will be called Only one time before any test tag, no matter how many test classes inside that tag or how many method annotated with `@Test`, it will be called only one time for each test tag,in the previous XML example `@BeforeTest` will be called twice, one time before`TestTag1` the second time before `TestTag2`   so it can be used to initialize common objects between different test classes inside one test tag.

`@BeforeClass` : It will be called Only one time before any test **class**, no matter how many method annotated with `@Test` inside this test class, it will be called only one time for each test class,in the previous `XML` example `@BeforeClass` will be called three times, one time before`TestClass1` the second time before `TestClass2` and the third time before `TestClass3` so it can be used to initialize common objects between different test methods inside one test class.

`@BeforeSuite` will be called once for the `suit1` suit

the order of calls will be as follow

```
@BeforeSuite
    @BeforeTest
        @BeforeClass
            @BeforeMethod
                @Test
```

To know more about `@BeforeMethod`, please refer to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52331616/1973933

Answer (score 2):

This is the TestNG hierarchy:
Test Suite -> Test -> Class -> Method

@BeforeTest is executed once before the execution of all methods in all classes within test tag.

**on the other hand;**

@BeforeClass is executed once before the execution of all methods within the class it is defined.

I have uploaded the script on my GitHub Profile. Here is a link for same. Please give a thumbs up if you like.

[Please have a look at github:](https://github.com/provivek2124/TestAnnotate/blob/main/src/package1/Class1.java)

Answer (score 1):

if you extend from another class this are the results:

```
parentTest - BeforeTest- parent     
testClass1 - BeforeTest- test1    
parentTest - BeforeClass- parent    
testClass1 - BeforeClass- test1    
parentTest - BeforeMethod- parent    
testClass1 - BeforeMethod- test1    
testClass1 - myTestMethod1    
testClass1 - AfterMethod- test1    
parentTest - AfterMethod- parent    
parentTest - BeforeMethod- parent    
testClass1 - BeforeMethod- test1    
testClass1 - myTestMethod2    
testClass1 - AfterMethod- test1    
parentTest - AfterMethod- parent
testClass1 - AfterClass- test1    
parentTest - AfterClass- parent
testClass1 - AfterTest- test1
parentTest – AfterTest- parent
```

Answer (score 1):

My opinions:

@BeforeClass:The annotated method will be run before the first test method *in the current class* is invoked

@BeforeTest:The annotated method will be run before any test method *in the current suite* is run

Answer (score 0):

```
@BeforeClass: The annotated method will be run before the first test method in the current class is invoked. 
@BeforeMethod: The annotated method will be run before each test method.

The annotations above will also be honored (inherited) when placed on a superclass of a TestNG class. This is useful for example to centralize test setup for multiple test classes in a common superclass.

In that case, TestNG guarantees that the "@Before" methods are executed in inheritance order (highest superclass first, then going down the inheritance chain), and the "@After" methods in reverse order (going up the inheritance chain).
```

To know more about TestNG annotations: https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations

Answer (score 0):

What is missing in the above answers is the usage difference between `@BeforeClass` and `@BeforeTest` annotations.

As it is clear that the method (most commonly the setup method) annotated with `@BeforeClass` will execute only once before all the testcases written in the class. And the method annotated with '@BeforeTest' will execute before every testcase regardless of their count/sequence/underline logic.

Therefore, `@BeforeClass` is used when our method has long calls with long execution time and the output of these calls will be unchanged by any of the testcases. For example, getting an API response in the setup method, which will be used by all the tests.
Whereas, `@BeforeTest@` is used when we need to do some cleanup stuff, and every test needs some fresh resource to start with. For example, one newly created order etc.