# Issue in using @BeforeTest annotation in testng

Tags: java, annotations, testng

I am writing automation code for my mobile site.

Class1:-

```
public class Sample{

    @BeforeTest
    public void createUser(){
    // code to create user
    }

    @Test
    public void verifyUser(){
    // code to verify user
    }


    @AfterTest
    public void deleteUser(){
    // code to delete user
    }

}
```

Like `Class1`. I have different classes such as `Class2`, `Class3`, `Class4`.

testing.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1">
    <test name="Regression1" parallel="false" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="Class1"/>
            <class name="Class2"/>          
            <class name="Class3"/>
            <class name="Class4"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Command to run:-

```
mvn -Dtests=testing.xml test
```

when i run above command, `@BeforeTest` from `Class1`, `Class2`, `Class3`, `Class4` are called first. It means 4 users are created firstly before running any test. Then only `Class1` Test is running then `Class2` and so on. Atlast `@AfterTest` from all classes are running(deleting all user atlast).

I don't want this scenario.

I need the following way to run my each test:-

1. create of user
2. verify of user
3. delete of user

I need my `Class1` executed first fully then `Class2` and so on.

Is there any change in annotation for testng i have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `BeforeMethod` instead of `BeforeTest`. The `BeforeTest` method will run before your `<test>` tag in `testng.xml` and not before your `@Test` method. 
And also use `AfterMethod` instead of `AfterTest` of course.

Check my answer for another similar question: [Difference between BeforeClass and BeforeTest in TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587454/difference-between-beforeclass-and-beforetest-in-testng/30591902#30591902)

Comment: I have two test method in one class. if i use BeforeMethod, its called for each test. i don't need it. I want BeforeMethod or BeforeTest to be called irrespective of all test methods and AfterMethod or AfterTest to be called end of all test methods.

Comment: If you have two test methods in your Test Class then use `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass`. So the order will be: beforeClass(), testMethod1(), testMethod2(), afterClass().