# Unable to execute after test method -TestNG

Tags: selenium, testng

In my TestNG framework, I want to execute `@AfterTest` method to quit a Browser session by calling a **method** from customer **Util** class. I am getting an error as **"Parameter 'Webdriver driver' is required by @Configuration on method TearDown but has not been marked @Optional or defined**"
After reading that error, I declared a parameter to AfterTest Method like below.

```
@AfterTest

public void TearDown(WebDriver driver){
    Util.tearDown(driver);

    }
```

Here is a teardown method from Util package

```
    public static void tearDown(WebDriver driver) {

    driver.quit();
    if (driver.toString().equals(null)) {
        logger.info(driver.toString() + " is closed ");
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? could you plz suggest how to fix this? thanks :)

Adding class file here

```
@Listeners({com.customerItestListener.CustomItestListener.class})

public class TC_CreateOnloadProposal {

WebDriver driver;

@Test

@Parameters({ "Url", "BemsID", "TransferType", "WrkTrnsfrTtle", "purpse" })

public void run(String Url, String BemsID, String TransferType, String WrkTrnsfrTtle, String purpse) {
    driver = BrowserFactory.getInstance("firefox", Url).getDriver();
    PageObjCreateExpressProposal pg_loc = PageFactory.initElements(driver, PageObjCreateExpressProposal.class);
    pg_loc.checkForElement(driver, pg_loc.Txt_Login, "set", BemsID);
    pg_loc.checkForElement(driver, pg_loc.Img_Logon, "click");
    pg_loc.checkForElement(driver, pg_loc.Lnk_onload, "click");
    pg_loc.checkForElement(driver, pg_loc.Img_CrtOrSelctPrpsl, "click");
}

@AfterTest

public void TearDown(){
    driver.quit();
}
```

`

Comment: I've made the below changes to AfterTest method- no luck
`@AfterTest
@parameters({"Webdriver driver"})
public void TearDown(WebDriver driver){
    Util.tearDown(driver);

    }`

Comment: Where have you initialized the driver object? Is it in the Util class? If so remove the passing of the driver to the method. If the driver is in initialized the Test class then make it a instance variable and pass it to Util.

Comment: `@AfterTest

public void TearDown(){
    Util.tearDown(driver);
    }` should work if you declared driver before

Comment: This error you are getting is because you are not passing `driver` to your `TearDown` method.

Comment: @Grasshopper I've initialized webdriver in my class & passing as an argument to a AfterTest method. Regardless of passing an argument, I can't get to work out with `@AfterTest` method even with simple codeas below

@AfterTest
 
 public void TearDown(){
  driver.quit();
 }

Comment: What is the exception you getting now? Can you add your test class to your question sow e can have a look?

Comment: @Grasshopper I've added to the code to question section.I can't get to run `@AfterTest` method

Comment: Are you getting any exception? Can you log or print a message in the aftertest method that it is getting called.

Comment: @nandeshkalyankar, As you have initialized the `driver` in the test class, there should be no problem in using it in `@AfterTest`. Why are you trying to quit the driver in `Utils` class as you are doing the same in `@AfterTest` method in test class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to run your `tearDown()` method after every `@Test` method, you should use `@AfterMethod` instead of `@AfterTest`. See my answer for this question: [Difference between BeforeClass and BeforeTest in TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587454/difference-between-beforeclass-and-beforetest-in-testng/30591902#30591902)

The other problem is that you want to use your Util class where the WebDriver is not initialized. The easiest way to include the `@AfterTest` or `@AfterMethod` methods in the same class where your test cases are, or if you want to store it in a separate class then create an abstract class and extend your Test Class with it. Example:

**AbstractTest class**

```
public class AbstractTest {
    protected Webdriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() {
        // init your webdriver
        this.driver = ...;
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() {
        this.driver.quit();
    }
}
```

**Your Test Class**

```
public class MyTests extends AbstractTest {
    @Test
    public void myCoolTest() {
        this.driver.get(...);
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

The reason `@AfterTest` method didn't execute is because I didn't include it in xml file. I am running this test As Run as TestNG xml.

Here are the changes I made to xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name ="ExpressModule">
<test name = "Express module Test">
    <parameter name="Url" value="http:XXXX"/>
    <parameter name="BemsID" value="95188"/>
    <parameter name="TransferType" value="Onload"/>
    <parameter name="WrkTrnsfrTtle" value="Onload"/>
    <parameter name="purpse" value="No Purpose"/>       
        <classes>
            <class name="com.wtms.ExpressProposalCreation.TC_CreateOnloadProposal"/>
            <methods>
            <include name="run"/>
            <include name="TearDown"/>
            </methods>
            </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```