# How to use @Before/@BeforeClass with @Autowired field

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have a test case which has an `@Autowired` field. I would like to have one method for setting up the test case, as it has many `@Test`-annotated methods that will rely on the same generated data, (for which I need the autowired class).

What's a good way to achieve this?

If I have the `@BeforeClass`, then I need to make the method static, which breaks the autowiring.

Comment: Can you add an external dependency to another well-known framework?

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz: Sure, what are you proposing?

Comment: I have added another solution.

Answer (score 4):

**1st solution**

Use [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/maven.html) instead.
`@Before*` annotations behave [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30591902/4280359) in TestNG.
No method annotated with `@Before*` has to be static.

```
@org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass
public void setUpOnce() {
   //I'm not static!
}
```

**2nd solution**

And if you don't want to do that, you can use [an execution listener from Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/support/AbstractTestExecutionListener.html#beforeTestClass-org.springframework.test.context.TestContext-) (`AbstractTestExecutionListener`).

You will have to annotate your test class like this:

```
@TestExecutionListeners({CustomTestExecutionListener.class})
public class Test {
    //Some methods with @Test annotation.
}
```

And then implement `CustomTestExecutionListener` with this method:

```
public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
    //Your before goes here.
}
```

Self-contained in one file that would look like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"commonContext.xml" })
@TestExecutionListeners({SimpleTest.class})
public class SimpleTest extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) {
        System.out.println("In beforeTestClass.");
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("In test.");
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks great, but my whole project has `JUnit` tests and I wasn't hoping to throw them away.

Comment: @carlspring, that is why I have added something else from Spring to my answer (no need to use TestNG, if you opt for the second solution) ;)

Comment: Can the test class itself be the listener?

Comment: So far used it as top-level class in another file. If it does not work, I would extend `AbstractTestExecutionListener` in an inner class... in the same `Test.java` file.

Comment: Grzegorz, it looks like your solution could do the trick, but I can't get it to work. Would you mind adding a really simple working example? I have this: https://gist.github.com/carlspring/662d8033fece212c3cd5718ed333142c and it's never hitting the `beforeTestClass` method. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Added a working example. No need to create yet another inner class (my bad). The `SimpleTest` class is enough ;)

Comment: I've almost gotten it to work, but the `@Autowired` class doesn't seem to be getting injected by Spring (which was my initial problem).

Comment: Will have another look at this in the evening, cause I'm on mobile now.

Comment: For the second solution, why can't I access the `@Autowired` spring stereo-typed services on the methods of `AbstractTestExecutionListener `. In addition to that, why can't I use any global variables on the class initialised on the same interface?

Answer (score 3):

I came up with the solution of creating a separate initialization method (not `setUp`) annotated with `@PostConstruct`. This is not really an elegant solution, but it makes sure that the autowired/injected fields are properly initialized by Spring before using them, (which was the initial problem with the statically `@BeforeClass` annotated method).

Comment: Thanks @carlspring. This works for me. Assuming there still isn't a better way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 0):

Using `Junit 5` you are allowed to use an `@Autowired` annotation in the static `@BeforeAll` context like this:

```java
public class TestClass {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void beforeAll(@Autowired ApplicationContext context) {
        context.doSomething() //possible now as autowired function parameter is used
    }
}
```