# Run Dataprovider after a Test

Tags: java, testng

I am curious how `Dataprovider` runs in a test suite?
I mean in which order things run?
example:

- `@Dataprovider`
- Test01
- Test02 -> populates the `Dataprovider`
- Test03
- Test04 -> uses the `Dataprovider`

Can Test04 run before Test2 and so, use an empty `Dataprovider`?

Answer (score 1):

You can set priority for the each tests. Based on the priority only mentioned for each test cases it will execute

```
@Test(priority=2)
public void Test1(){
  //...
}


@Test(priority=1)
public void Test2(){
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As said @Mukesh, `priority` can run (start) your Test2 before Test1, but it doesn't garant that Test2 will be completed at moment, when Test1 starting - so, in this approach, your test data can be empty. 
For your purpose and such garantee you must use `groups` and `dependsOnGroups` parameters:

```
@Test(groups = "groupA")
public void test2() {}

@Test(dependsOnGroups = "groupA")
public void test1() {}
```

Another moment is that tests, depending on other tests, is not good practice, i think - 
better to use `@Before` annotations.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but does `Dataprovider` run right before the methods that need it? Or it runs once before all tests(because it is placed at the top of the test class) and again before the test that uses it?

Comment: @Daniel, syntax of `Dataprovider` allow us flexible using it for providing data **straight to test** (its method parameters), that needs them. I'm now adding new comment here with sample and links, see it in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use priority as mentioned in above answer. Here is the execution order of priorities, Lower priorities will be scheduled first.

Example: @Test(priority=1) will execute first.
         @Test(priority=2) will execute second.

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel, if we need do any **prepare** actions before running tests (for example, open connection to DB and prepare test data in it, or call other not-testing-here services, or put *test data, that will be used in most of all tests*) - we must use one of `@Before` annotations. They can be very useful and flexy, good answer with code about them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587454/difference-between-beforeclass-and-beforetest-in-testng).
What about `@Dataprovider` - it provides data straight to tests, those need it:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "Authentication")
public void errorMessageOnLoginWithBadCredentials(String email, String password, String errMsg) {
            User badUser = new User(email, password);

            at(LoginPage.class)
                    .loginAs(badUser)
                    .errorMessage
                    .shouldHave(exactText(errMsg));
}

@DataProvider(name = "Authentication")
public static Object[][] credentials() {
            return new Object[][]{
                    {" ", " ", "Username is required"},
                    {"user1@gmail.com", "UserTest@123", "Login and / or password do not match"},
                    {"user1@gmail.com", " ", "Password is required"},
                    {"ololo@ololo.com", "admin", "Login and / or password do not match"}
            };
}
```

To avoid ugly syntax of `Object[][] (or Iterator<Object[]>)`, you can also use `@DataSupplier` (see [here](https://github.com/sskorol/test-data-supplier)), adapted for using with Stream API, for example.

Hope this be useful.

Comment: Have you solved your problem, @Daniel? All is clear now?