# @BeforeTest @AfterTest not executing in Child Class, @BEforeClass executed in Parent class

Tags: testng

## My base class

```
package selenium.setup;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

public class SeleniumBaseTest {
    protected final static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> webDriver = new ThreadLocal<>();
        
    @BeforeClass
    @Parameters({"browser","baseURL"})
    public void Setup(String browser, String baseURL) throws Exception{
        webDriver.set(BrowserManager.doBrowserSetup(browser));
        System.out.println("Before Test Thread ID: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
        //get URL
        webDriver.get().get(baseURL);
        webDriver.get().manage().window().maximize();
        webDriver.get().manage().deleteAllCookies();
        webDriver.get().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown(){
        webDriver.get().quit();
        System.out.println("After Test Thread ID: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
        webDriver.remove();
    }
}
```

## Child class

```
`package selenium.trials;

import java.time.Duration;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import selenium.setup.SeleniumBaseTest;
import selenium.utils.WebElementUtility;

public class SeleniumDragnDrop extends SeleniumBaseTest{
    Logger logger;
    WebDriver driver;
    
    @BeforeTest(alwaysRun=true)
    public void beforeTest(ITestContext testContext){
      logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());
      driver = webDriver.get();
      
      logger.info("In dragNDrop beforeTest: Thread ID: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
    
    @Test
    public void dragNDrop() throws InterruptedException {
        logger.info("In dragNDrop Thread ID: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
        
    WebElementUtility.clickOn(driver,driver.findElement(By.linkText("Drag and Drop")), Duration.ofSeconds(15));
        
    WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.id("column-a"));
    WebElement dest = driver.findElement(By.id("column-b"));
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.dragAndDrop(source, dest).build().perform();
    logger.info("After dragNDrop Thread ID: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
    
    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() {
    logger.info("In dragNDrop tearDown : Thread ID: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
}`
```

## config file  - testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestSuite" thread-count="2" parallel="classes">
<parameter name="browser" value="Chrome"/>
<parameter name="baseURL" value="https://the-internet.herokuapp.com"/>

<test name="SeleniumTrials"  preserve-order="true">
<!-- 
    <packages>
        <package name="selenium.trials"/>
    </packages> -->
    <classes>
        <class name="selenium.trials.SeleniumDragnDrop"/>
        
        <class name="selenium.trials.SeleniumAlerts"/>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

### Problem

When I run the testngSuite, @BeforeClass method setup() in Parent Class - SeleniumBaseTest.java is executed. However, @BeforeTest method in child class - SeleniumDragnDrop.java is not executed.
Hence test fails as driver variable is not initialized

I initialize the ThreadLocal<WebDriver> in parent class @BeforeClass method and in Child class @BeforeTest method I am storing the reference to it in WebDriver object. However @BeforeTest method is never executed and the driver variable remains uninitialzed.

Answer (score 0):

I could find my answer in this post - [Difference between BeforeClass and BeforeTest in TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587454/difference-between-beforeclass-and-beforetest-in-testng).

@BeforeTest runs prior to @BeforeClass. Hence the driver variable was null as it was initialized in BeforeClass which runs after BeforeTest.